# Attaching files to Web Service response in Java

Tags: java, web-services, response, attachment, mtom

How to attach files to a Web Service response in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what library you are using but we use CXF and MTOM

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html